# Difference between RMS and EDF when the period is equal to the deadline

Tags: real-time, scheduler, scheduling

I am trying to understand the difference between these two scheduling techniques. Everything is okay until I found an example where the deadline and the period are equal.

[image: Example]

What is the difference between the two techniques if A has the highest priority and C has the lowest one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Rate Monotonic Scheduling (RMS)** is a real time preemptive scheduling algorithm. It is used for processes which meet the following conditions:

1) Processes should be periodic and there should be a time period for every process;

2) Every process must require the same amount of CPU time on each burst;

3) Every process should be independent;

4) If a process is not periodic, then it should not have a deadline.

**Earliest Deadline First (EDF)** Scheduling is a type of real time scheduling algorithm. In the EDF, the first two conditions of the RMS algorithm are not required. In EDF, processes are sorted by using their deadlines. A process which has the earliest deadline is run first. If a new process is ready, its deadline is checked. If the deadline is before the running process, then the new process pre-empts the running process.

Comment: Does this mean that if all the 4 conditions were satisfied, then the algorithms and implementations would be exactly the same for EDF and RMS?